# php echoing blank datatable for json mysql columns

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to echoing out the values from database. All tables shows properly but json datatable shows blank.
Php Code

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM multiurl WHERE id='$id'";
$query_run= mysqli_query($con, $query);
foreach($query_run as $row){
```

Html Table Format

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="form-control-label" for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Urls [Edit only url and name ]</label>
<textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" value="<?php echo $row['urls']?>"></textarea>
</div>
```

Mysql `urls` column data format

```
{"url":"name","url":"name"...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of a `textarea` is not specified using the `value` attribute, it's put into the HTML text.

You should also use `htmlspecialchars()` to encode all the characters, to prevent XSS.

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['urls'])?></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but this method works only in input tag. Textarea still shows blank.

Comment: You're missing the `<` before `textarea`.

Comment: I Missed here by mistake i put correctly in code.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You don't use `value` for textareas, you put the contents between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`